# Angular compile error 'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error while running npm start

ERROR in @angular\cdk\bidi\typings\index.ts(13,2): Error during template compile of 'BidiModule'   Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'     'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.

My package.json is as :

```
  "name": "cmarvel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "npm run env -s && ng build --prod",
    "start": "npm run env -s && ng serve --aot --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "serve:sw": "npm run build -s && npx http-server ./dist -p 4200",
    "lint": "ng lint && stylelint \"src/**/*.scss\" --syntax scss && htmlhint \"src\" --config .htmlhintrc",
    "test": "npm run env -s && ng test",
    "test:ci": "npm run env -s && npm run lint -s && ng test --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "e2e": "npm run env -s && ng e2e",
    "translations:extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/translations/template.json --format=json --clean --sort --marker extract",
    "docs": "hads ./docs -o",
    "env": "ngx-scripts env npm_package_version",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"./{src,e2e}/**/*.{ts,js,html,scss}\"",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --list-different \"./{src,e2e}/**/*.{ts,js,html,scss}\"",
    "generate": "ng generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jsoneditor": "^5.28.1",
    "angular-alert-module": "^2.0.3",
    "angular4-jsoneditor": "^1.0.7",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jsoneditor": "^5.32.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^4.0.5",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.3",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^2.3.4",
    "@ngx-rocket/scripts": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.112",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.13",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "hads": "^1.7.3",
    "htmlhint": "^0.11.0",
    "https-proxy-agent": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.3",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.10.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.12.0",
    "stylelint": "~10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^5.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "~3.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "~18.3.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "~3.6.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.16.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.14.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.0"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": "*.scss",
        "options": {
          "singleQuote": false
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```